# Add text before and after the bar component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add some text `before` and `after` the `bar` like the image below.

```
<div class="container">

<div  class="progress progress-info
     progress-striped">
  <div id="storage-component" class="bar"
       style="width: 20%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bar"
       style="width: 60%;"></div>
</div>  
</div>
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/i1xnufa3

Before and after method seems not to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ep9vD/

You had a typo in your code by missing the closing quotation mark and also were targetting the wrong element.  Also not sure if your demo was including jQuery.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".progress-info").before("<div>efererer</div>").after("<span>after-text</span>");
});
```

Comment: Correct. Also, are the `<div>` and `<span>` needed? I think it would work if the correct element was used and the typo was fixed :)

Comment: No, they're not needed, was just demonstrating as they can be used then to easily style and control the appended values.

Comment: why are the text not inline to the div bar... it comes in a new line